# Numbering of Sections

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'm using chapters in my thesis. Within chapters I'm using sections for structuring.
Most sections are rather short however, so I don't want them to have/display a number.

Basically what I want should look like the following:

1 Chapter

Section A

Def 1.1

...

Proposition 1.5

Section B

Def 1.6

I tried using

`\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\c@section\else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
    \fi}
\makeatother`

The output however looks like

1 Chapter

Section A

Def 1.2

How can I tell LaTeX to number the code the way I tried above?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not a simple `\renewcommand{\thesection}{}`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe?

Comment: @Bernard: I don't know how.. Could you give me an example that should produce the output I'd like?

Comment: Yes, but could you post a minimal (yet complete) code that we can play with?

Comment: Of course, one second.

Comment: Actually, there is no need to. I was able to deduce what I wanted from the answer from @Ulrich Diez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I tell LaTeX to number the code the way I tried above? Thanks in advance!

Some nitpicking:

You can't "tell" LaTeX to number (in whatsoever ways) the code because LaTeX must not modify (in whatsoever ways) the .tex-source code of a document while "numbering code" can be subsumed under "modifying code".

But you can "tell" LaTeX to number in the way you *exhibited* above some items of sectioning that may be represented by portions of .tex-source-code and that appear when viewing/displaying/printing the .pdf-file which comes into being as one of the results of compiling the .tex-source-code. ;-)

With most document classes for LaTeX you have sectioning commands like `\chapter`, `\section`, etc.
With most document classes for LaTeX for each of these sectioning commands a so-called "starred" variant exists which does produce the item of sectioning without a sectioning number (and without an entry in the table of contents, and without a bookmark in case of using **hyperref**, and without changing the page headings).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{Definition}{Def}[chapter]
\newtheorem{Proposition}[Definition]{Proposition}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section*{Section A}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section A}
\begin{Definition}...\end{Definition}
\begin{Definition}...\end{Definition}
\begin{Definition}...\end{Definition}
\begin{Definition}...\end{Definition}
\begin{Proposition}...\end{Proposition}
\section*{Section B}
\begin{Definition}...\end{Definition}

\end{document}
```

Page 1:

[image]

Page 2:

[image]

Comment: Ah, sorry I was kind of sloppy there: I'd like Section A to get listed in the table of contents if possible. I just don't want it to have a number (displayed).
Also: Thanks a lot for the technical correction as well as your time and effort.

Comment: @user190728 I just added an  `\addcontentsline` which will cause creation of the corresponding entry within the table of contents...